# How can I execute batch stored procedure call from java code?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an procedure in oracle database which takes two parameters:

```
procedure some_procedure(int x, int y)
```

My project is using spring boot + hibernate. So, the question is how I can execute this stored procedure using batching (for example 100) from java code?

I've found some examples with usage of @Procedure annotation and also with StoredProcedureQuery - but those were only for simple not batching call.

And also could someone explain when I should use @Procedure annotation instead of StoredProcedureQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling stored procedure, you get OUT parameters and can,t change it through calling. If stored procedure return ref_cursor, and you want to limit records, change stored procedure.

With `StoredProcedureQuery` you will write more code and manually manage calling process (get entityManager, open transaction, make a call, close transaction ...). With JPA repository you describe procedure by annotations and go. But both approaches work.

UPD:

Oh, little misunderstanding. You can call procedure several times in one transaction with StoredProcedureQuery, is this what you want? Code looks like this:

```
public class ProcedureCall {
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public void executeProcedureWithoutResult(Map<String, ?> parameters, String procedureName) {
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery1 = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(procedureName);
    StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery2 = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(procedureName);

    fillProcedureParameters(procedureQuery1, parameters);
    fillProcedureParameters(procedureQuery2, parameters);

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        procedureQuery1.execute();
        procedureQuery2.execute();

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        rollbackTransaction(e, em.getTransaction());
    } finally {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

private void fillProcedureParameters(StoredProcedureQuery sp, Map<String, ?> parameters) {
    if (parameters.size() > 0) {
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, ?> rec : parameters.entrySet()) {
            sp.setParameter(rec.getKey(), rec.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it even works, if you execute one procedureQuery twice, but I didn't try.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, so my stored procedure doesn't return any result and I don't need it. Is there a way to call such procedure several times in one sql query (I mean execute batch call)?

Comment: Thanks for example, yes, It's kinda what I was looking for. Also fould a little better solution with usage of CallableStatement:
`CallableStatement cstmt = c.prepareCall("{call pTestBug49831(?)}");
cstmt.setObject(1, "abc", Types.VARCHAR, 32);
cstmt.addBatch();
cstmt.setObject(1, "def", Types.VARCHAR, 32);
cstmt.addBatch();  `

But anyway I will approve your answer